# How well Users Points Voting API works with FiveStars module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, fivestar, userpoints

I'm using "Users Points Voting API" module to combine "User Points" module and "Fivestar" module.

It works, but not as expected.
When an user rate a post, the author gains N points.
If an user removes its vote, the author loses the N points.

N is a fixed number (I set it in the settings). It is fixed, and not related to the number of stars, it depends on the number of votes one receives and not how good and how bad are these votes (1,2.. or 5 stars).

Can anybody confirm what I've written ? It seems that the module should work differently because it allows to specify positive and negative votes. Maybe it has not been fully developed for the Fivestar module.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All votes in the fivestar module is positive in that sense that 1 star is above zero. So the problem is not so much the integration itself, but that the two modules don't mix that well. User points react on positive/negative votes, but since all votes in fivestar are positive, 1 star will gain the same result as 5 star vote.

You could argue this is a bad idea, but this is how it was designed.